# Https production certificate path. Jhipster 4.13

Tags: jhipster

I want to put https in my project jhipster.

I have created a certificate.

And I have put it in the root path of my project.

And in my application-dev.yml I have configured it:

```
server:
 port: 8443
  ssl:
    key-store: keystore.p12
    key-store-password: XXXXX
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    key-alias: myproyect
```

I start it and it works correctly

My problem is when I upload it to production

When packaging, when I display in production, it tells me that my certificate does not exist.

I do not know if I should leave it in another route in production or I have to do something so that when I pack it I copy the certificate to a specific route.

Answer (score 0):

The `server.port.ssl.key-store` property must point to an existing keystore on the disk of the machine running the app. An alternative is to add the keystore inside the jar package so that you can access it on the classpath.

For example if your keystore.p12 is located in `src/main/resources`, it will be copied at the root of your classpath when packaging your app (`target/classes` with maven). Then you can configure your properties like this in `application-prod.yml`:

```
server:
  ssl:
    key-store: classpath:keystore.p12
```